# Get suffix from Expressjs routing

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I have requests like the followings:

```
/name-of-anything-1/another-name-2/and-a-third-name-3
```

I want to be able to get the suffix in a param (`-1`, `-2` and `-3` in this cases). I had the next route but doesn't work:

> ```
> app.get('/:optional-:suffix?*', function(req, res) {
>   //anything
> ```
>
> }

I obtain the first `'-'` and I need the last one and the rest at 'optional' param.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just split the whole string at hyphen `-` and get the last one out

```
app.get('/:optional', function(req, res){
    var suffix = req.params[optional].split('-').reverse()[0];
}
```